# Out of $9$ women and $3$ men, a committee of $6$ members is formed. If at least $1$ man is always included in committee, then there are __ ways?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Out of $9$ women and $3$ men, a committee of $6$ members is formed. If at
>   least $1$ man is always included in committee, then there are __ ways?

Here is the logic I tried:

Case A: $3$ M, $3$ W
Case B: $2$ M, $4$ W
Case C: $1$ M, $5$ W

Using Combinations:

${3\choose1} \times {9\choose5} + {3\choose2} \times {9\choose4} + {3\choose3} \times {9\choose3} = 840$ [the correct answer].

*The problem is that I am about to take aptitude exam for college, and I will not be having enough time to solve long calculation, and calculators won't be allowed, too.*

**So, what is the shortest method or trick  for solving this kind of question? I will be having only 1 minute for the question and the test will be MCQ based.**

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi Bilal, welcome to StackExchange! Can you tell us what you've tried so far? That will help us provide you with better explanations/hints. Also, if you can in the future, use LaTeX to format your questions.

Comment: @scoopfaze , I have mentioned what i have tried and what is the problem.Kindly check the description.

Comment: I have read the question, but you’re asking for a faster method of calculation since you believe what you’ve done takes too long. I am asking you what else you have tried (if anything).

Comment: How many committees are there?  How many with NO men? And the rest??

Comment: @scoopfaze , I don't know any other method of the question so i haven't experiment anything new on this question.

Comment: Please don't write whole sentences with CAPITAL LETTERS.

Comment: @DJohnM , Take it easy bro . I committee of 6 members is defined in question . That's all described in question :)

Comment: @user , New User here.Will be careful next time.NOTED!

Comment: And how many of these 6 member committees are there, and how many are all women, and how would you describe the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you are asked a question that contains the words "at least 1" it is quite useful to analyze if it is possible to approach the problem from the "complementary case perspective", for example:

Let A be the number of possible committes, without restrictions. You may work this out, but is as simple as choosing $6$ people from $12$.$$|A|=|\{\text{Number of possible committes}\}|={9+3 \choose 6}={12 \choose 6}=\frac{12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7}{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}=\\=11\cdot7\cdot4\cdot3=924=\text{ posibilites.}$$

Now you want to look at the number of possible committes where there aren't any men. So define $A_0=\{\text{Number of possible committes without men}\}$ which is precisely the complementary subset (in A) of what you are asked.

$$|A_0|={9 \choose 6}=\frac{9\cdot8\cdot7}{3\cdot2\cdot1}=7\cdot4\cdot3=84=\text{ posibilites.}$$

So now you want to figure out the cardinal number of the following set: $\overline{A_{0}}=\{\text{Number of possible committes with at least one man}\}$.

$$|\overline{A_{0}}|=|A|-|A_{0}|=924-84=840\text{ possible committes.}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using your cases: $\binom{3}{1}\binom{9}{5} = 3 \cdot \frac{9!}{5!4!} = \frac{3 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6}{24} = 9 \times 7 \times 6 = 9 \times 42 = 360+18=378$. Just cancelling in fractions and relatively simple arithmetic..

$\binom{3}{2}\binom{9}{4}=3 \cdot \frac{9!}{5!4!}$, so the same as the previous.

$\binom{3}{3}\binom{9}{3} = \frac{9!}{3!6!}  =\frac{9 \times 8 \times 7}{3 \times 2 \times 1} = \frac{3 \times 4 \times 7}{1 \times 1 \times 1}= 12 \times 7 = 84$

And $378 + 378 + 84$ should be doable... (10 seconds on paper, for me just now)

Another idea is to take all committees of $6$ out of $12$ people, i.e.  $\binom{12}{6} = \frac{12\times 11 \times 10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7}{6\times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1} =  11 \times 3 \times 4 \times 7 = 77 \times 12 = 924$ and subtract from that the committees without men, so only women ie.. $\binom{9}{6} = \frac{9\times 8 \times 7}{6} = 3 \times 4 \times 7 = 84$ and get the same result.

Comment: He want another method

Comment: @EduardoS. He wanted to see it could be done without calculator, and I just did. People get fixated on calculators. Often unnecessarily.